# Parse YAML file to Java classes

Tags: java, yaml, snakeyaml

I have a YAML file and what I need to do is to create appropriate classes so that I can parse it using this code:

```
InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
        Root myYaml = yaml.loadAs(inputStream, Root.class);
```

Here is the YAML file:

```
project:
  name: My Software Project
  description: The description of the project
suites:
  - BackEndTests:
    - Test1:
        enabled: true
        command: echo Test
    - Test2:
        enabled: true
        command: echo Test 2
        description: This test does something too
  - UITests:
    - Test3:
        enabled: true
        command: echo Test 3
        description: Hello world
    - Test4:
        enabled: false
        command: echo Test 4
```

I created the following classes:

```
public class Root {
     private Project project;
     private List<Suite> suites;
}
// setters and getters

public class Project {
     private String name;
     private String description;
}
// setters and getters

public class Suite {
     private String name;
     private List<Test> tests;
}
// setters and getters

public class Test {
     private boolean enabled;
     private String command;
     private String description;
}
// setters and getters
```

I got this error message for my application, build with Spring Boot:
[Click here to see full error message](https://pastebin.com/6gU7wVf5)

I always included setters, getters and even constructors for each class. Can somebody **propose how to structure the classes so that I can parse the YAML file without any errors**? Also, **is it okay if I put additional fields to the classes** (other than these listed in the yaml), because I need to use them later for other purposes? An example:

```
public class Project {
     private Integer id; // adding field that is not contained in the yaml
     private String name;
     private String description;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would suggest trying to generate YML from data and comparing that to the YML you believe is correct. That might give you some insights.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Mind that *they didn't work out* is not an error description. Please edit your question to include a description of the behavior you encountered. Also, please stick to Java syntax when describing Java classes and generally try to supply code as [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that others can reproduce your problem.

Comment: As per the YAML you shared, Inside suite class you have to add two objects named BackEndTests and UITests. and inside those classes will have the object of Test with separate name Test1 and Test2,... You can't use List as both the objects have different names

Comment: There are similar looking objects in your YAML but still you can't use List bcoz they all have different key name. You can use the same class but you have to declare the objects separately for each of them

Comment: @RanjanMohanty The problem is that the application must parse different YAMLs each time it is run, with different count of tests.

Comment: Then you will have to change the YAML format

Comment: @RanjanMohanty If I convert it to JSON is there a way to parse the JSON file to the classes?

Comment: You can get the content of the file as a json string and use Gson to parse the content

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the YAML format, then the correct format would be

```
project:
  description: The description of the project
  name: My Software Project
suites:
  - name: BackEndTests
    tests:
      - command: echo Test
        enabled: true
        name: Test1
      - command: echo Test 2
        description: This test does something too
        enabled: true
        name: Test 2
  - name: UITests
    tests:
      - command: echo Test 3
        description: Hello world
        enabled: true
        name: Test3
      - command: echo Test 4
        enabled: false
        name: Test4
```

And the classes will be:

```
public class Root {
     private Project project;
     private List<Suite> suites;
}
// setters and getters

public class Project {
     private String name;
     private String description;
}
// setters and getters

public class Suite {
     private String name;
     private List<Test> tests;
}
// setters and getters

public class Test {
     private String name;
     private boolean enabled;
     private String command;
     private String description;
}
// setters and getters
```